# why after running react-native run, say me "Unable to resolve module" + lerna

Tags: node.js, react-native, yarnpkg, lerna, react-native-web

i have a monorepo project with lerna and i have app, web and common packages in monorepo folder. my app package is react-native project and my web package is react-native-web project. i add common dependency in web and app package from lerna add command. the result of my web project is fine but when i run app project, alert me "Unable to resolve module". while i find the common folder in node_modules folder in app package root. why react-native not found my common dependency?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBag2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCbma.png)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that Metro is ignoring smylinks. I've been Googling for hours and I've finally found a fix that works with `"react-native": "^0.61.5"` and `metro "^0.54.1"` (and I think it's also the cleanest solution).

It's this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@carimus/metro-symlinked-deps

So you simply need to change your `metro.config.js` as per documentation and don't forget to add your shared lerna package to `package.json` of the package where you are going to be using it (this looks to work a bit different from my other packages, I can import shared one there without package.json entry).